# armhf build of ethereum

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I'm having trouble building from source and/or finding a prebuilt binary (ideally this would be statically-linked) of ethereum to begin mining.  Is anyone looking at this build failure?

https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum/+build/9719707

Answer (score 1):

The error in the Launchpad nightly builds is the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sbuild-build-depends-ethereum-dummy : Depends: golang but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm assuming as long as you ensure the `golang` package is installed on your machine, then you shouldn't hit the same dependency error.

`armhf` is basically floating point support on a 32-bit instruction set, which I assume you're running on something like RPi. As an alternative you could try using the `armv7` binary found on the [Downloads](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) page. Note that `armv7` doesn't have the floating-point hardware extension...

> Is anyone looking at this build failure?

I don't know who this would fall to.